# How to edtit packages native code in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using kiosk_mode in my flutter project, but I want it to show my custom PIN code always when I will exit kiosk mode. In order to do that I need to edid package's native Android code. How to do that?

Is there any documentation or tutorial? I can not find anything

package I am relating:
https://pub.dev/packages/kiosk_mode

In its github I found a path:
"mews-flutter/kiosk_mode/android/src/main/kotlin/com/mews/kiosk_mode/KioskModePlugin.kt"

there is a line of code:

```
    private fun stopKioskMode(result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        activity?.stopLockTask()
        result.success(null)
        kioskModeHandler.emit()
    }
```

I want edid that line of code, every time program goes there I want to first show some popup, and then edid that in order to show my custom PIN code